# Is ternary operator allowed to evaluate both operands in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

While porting some C code to Windows, I've discovered an interesting ternary operator behavior in MSVC++. It appears that compiler evaluates both branches around `? :` in the following example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
struct S {
    int x;
};

int getNum() {
    printf("get num\n");
    return 4;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct S s = argc ? (struct S) { .x = getNum() } : (struct S) { .x = getNum() };
    printf("%d\n", s.x);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
get num
get num
4
```

But, GCC and Clang evaluate `getNum()` only once. Which behavior is correct or allowed by the standard?

Comment: Only one of the expressions after the question mark can be evaluated legitimately.  On the face of it, MSVC++ is wrong and Clang and GCC are correct.

Comment: However, since compound literals are not part of Standard C++ (AFAIK), it isn't clear that the code should compile as C++ — if it does so, it does so using an implementation-defined extension, and maybe the different definitions of that extension provides some mitigating circumstance for why the code behaves as it does in MSVC++ vs GCC and Clang.

Comment: This is Visual Studio 2019 (16.3.9). Actually, source code file has *.c extension, would that imply C mode?

Comment: The `.c` extension normally implies C code.  If it is being compiled as C, then it is hard to work out what gives the compiler licence to evaluate both initializers — in the ordinary course of events, it shouldn't.  There might be something documented somewhere in the MSVC documentation about it, but it's unlikely.

Comment: Makes sense, this question should probably be edited to mention C instead of C++. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The problem is the cast. It first runs the cast on both operands. If you change it to `(struct S){.x=argc?...` it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure how much it counts in your defence, but the question was originally tagged with both C and C++.  However, you should rarely tag with both languages, and the question was fairly explicit about it being C++ and not C, so I removed the C tag.

Comment: @TheFailurebyDesign: The 'cast' is a C11 'compound literal', defined in [§6.5.2.5 Compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn’t know how to call it; if you change it, it works as expected. If this is how it should work or not, you probably know better. The way the OP constructed the statement looks unusual to me.

Comment: @TheFailurebyDesign — I agree it is unusual, not least because the two expressions after the `?` are the same (there's no obvious need for the conditional at all, therefore).  The designated initializers are valid in C, but not in (current) Standard C++ (they're added to C++20).  I'm not sure about compound literals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to C++11 [§5.16.1 Conditional operator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.cond#1):

> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It is evaluated and if it
>   is true, the result of the conditional expression is the value of the
>   second expression, otherwise that of the third expression. **Only one
>   of the second and third expressions is evaluated**. Every value
>   computation and side effect associated with the first expression is
>   sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated
>   with the second or third expression.

According to C11 [§6.5.15 Conditional operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15):

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its
>   evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated). **The second operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only
>   if the first compares equal to 0;** the result is the value of the
>   second or third operand (whichever is evaluated), converted to the
>   type described below.

Comment: @Ayxan The OP's understanding is in line with what is written in the standards. So does this mean MSVC++ is doing something wrong?

Comment: @babon — It's almost certain that MSVC (or MSVC++) is mishandling the ternary operator.